# Checking if matrix has a value

Tags: python, list

If I have a matrix where it prints all zeros so:

```
m=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

I want to check if after I filled in with different numbers whether or not there any zeros left. Just has to return a boolean `True` or `False`.

```
m=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
>> True
m=[[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
>> False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and `not`

```
>>> m=[[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
>>> not any(j==0 for i in m for j in i)
False
>>> m=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
>>> not any(j==0 for i in m for j in i)
True
```

`any` returns `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, it returns `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution that makes use of Numpy's [count_nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) instead of list comprehensions

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
>>> m = np.asarray(m)
>>> np.count_nonzero(m) != m.size
False

>>> m=[[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
>>> m = np.asarray(m)
>>> np.count_nonzero(m) != m.size
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) with [`not in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

```
>>> m = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]
>>> all(0 not in x for x in m)
True

>>> m = [[1,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]]
>>> all(0 not in x for x in m)
False
```